# EmptyView on programmatically created ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

I try to apply an EmptyView to a programmatically created ListView. That looks like this:

```
ListView lv = new ListView(getActivity());

CustomAdapter ca = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),data);

lv.setAdapter(ca);

lv.setEmptyView(createEmptyView("TEST TEXT"));



private TextView createEmptyView(String text) {
        TextView emptyView = new TextView(getActivity());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        emptyView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        emptyView.setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);
        emptyView.setText(text);
        emptyView.setTextSize(16);
        emptyView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        emptyView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        emptyView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        return emptyView;
}
```

The ListView is displayed in a ViewPager. The EmptyView is not displayed when the list (data = ArrayList) and I don't know why. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Look at this blog http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/06/20/listview-tips-tricks-1-handle-emptiness/ although this does not directly answer your query

Comment: you have also to add the ListView to your fragment/activity .

Comment: @Blackbelt of course i already did this... I can see the ListView and its content if there is some content. Just need to know how to add the EmptyView

Comment: got it. But to see the emptyview, your listview has to be empty, right ?

Comment: @Raghunandan I have no ListActivity and I can't do this in xml so this article does not help me :/

Comment: @Blackbelt yes right. Like I mentioned `data` is an ArrayList and when it's empty the emptyview should show up I guess

Comment: @user1794338 it need not be ListActivity. Concept is the same.

Comment: maybe the background color of the edit text is black ?

Comment: no, it's a kind of gray, so you can see the text clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my trick was the following:

I added the EmptyView and the ListView to an extra RelativeLayout and then added this RelativeLayout to the ViewPager. That worked very well :)

```
RelativeLayout rlVP = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
rlVP.setLayoutParams(params2);

TextView emptyView = createEmptyView("Blabla test");
rlVP.addView(emptyView);
lv.setEmptyView(emptyView);
rlVP.addView(lv);
```